# bootstrap validator is not working with dynamic fields with same name

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrapvalidator

Html form for input :

```
        <form action="/admin/save_vehicle/" method="POST" id="vehicleForm">
                <input type="hidden" name="vendor_id" value="{{vendor_id}}">
                {%csrf_token%}
                <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label>Vehicle No</label>
                            <input type="text" name="editors[]" required class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                            <label>Mileage</label>
                            <input type="text" name="mileage" required class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <label>Chassis No</label>
                            <input type="text" name="chassis_no" required class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Vehicle Category</label>
                            <select name="category" class="form-control" required>
                                <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                {% if category.count > 0 %}
                                {% for category in category%}
                                <option value="{{category.id }}">{{category.category_name}}</option>
                                {%endfor%}
                                {%else%}
                                <option value="">Category not found</option>
                                {%endif%}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label>Status</label>
                            <select name="status" class="form-control" required>
                                <option value="1">Active</option>
                                <option value="2">In active</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input_fields_wrap"></div>
        
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary add_field_button mt-2">Add Vehicle</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Submit" class="default" name="Save">
        
            </form>
```

Dynamic generated form elements code :

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
                var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
                var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
                var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
        
                var x = 1; //initlal text box count
                $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                        x++; //text box increment
                        $(wrapper).append('<div class="mt-2"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-3 form-group"><input type="text" name="editors[]" required class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-1"><input type="text" name="mileage" required class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name="chassis_no" required class="form-control"></div><div class="col-md-2"><select name="category" class="form-control"><option value="">Select Category</option>{% if category.count > 0 %}{% for category in category%}<option value="{{category.id }}">{{category.category_name}}</option>{%endfor%}{%else%}<option value="">Category not found</option>{%endif%}</select></div><div class="col-md-2"><select name="status" class="form-control" required><option value="1">Active</option><option value="2">In active</option></select></div><a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a></div></div>'); //add input box
                    }
                });
        
                $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
                    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
                })
            });
```

Bootstarp validator validations :

```
$('#vehicleForm').bootstrapValidator({
        fields: {
            'editors[]': {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Vehicle No is required'
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    });
```

This is what i am getting in result :
[image]

What I actually want is I want to validate all dynamic fields but it is validating only the first field. dynamic fields are not getting validate what I am doing wrong here can anyone please help me related this ??

I have taken an example from
https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator/blob/master/demo/multiple.html
Bit it is not working in my case I don't know why

Comment: @Barmar do you have any solution related to this ??

Comment: Is there any solution related to this problem ?? please suggest me i am stuck here

Comment: Please take it easy with the tag-spam.  The Bootstrap Validator, Bootstrap Validator 1000 Hz, and the jQuery Validate plugin are three completely different plugins.  Edited.

Comment: The issue is that all these added elements has the same name. Give them a different name